# Change of coordinates and vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

So I am studying Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and I am trying to understand how to go from one coordinate representation of a Vector field to another. In particular this is the excersice :[image: Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds p.101]

So this is exactly what confuses me : How to change the "*coefficient functions*". I understand how to the relations of the tangent vectors but I have no clues as to have to transform their coefficients. Is it as simple as substituing?

Comment: It is: $x^2=r^2\cos^2\theta$, etc.

Comment: Hint: you should consider two coordinate systems $(x_1,\dots, x_n),(\tilde{x}_1,\dots, \tilde{x}_n)$ defined on an open subset of the manifold. Each of them generates $n$ vector fields independent at each point (you get them using partial derivatives)  (also called a local reference frame  for the tangent bundle), these are the $\frac \partial {\partial x^i}, \frac \partial {\partial \tilde{x}^i}$. Now try to express one of the $\frac \partial {\partial x^i}$  in terms of the others $\frac \partial {\partial \tilde{x}^i}$, use $\frac \partial {\partial x^i} = d (x_1,\dots, x_n)^{-1} (e_i) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: With the chain's rule we have 
$$\frac{\partial(\ \ )}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial(\ \ )}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial(\ \ )}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x},$$
i.e. you can see that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}+
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},$$
as an operator.
Similarly
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}=
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial y}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}+
\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},$$

Now, if 
$$x=\rho\cos\theta,$$
$$y=\rho\sin\theta,$$
you going to get $V=\rho\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\rho}$, taking into account that
$$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2},$$
$$\theta=\arctan\frac{y}{x}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much ! This really clears my doubts and confusion! It took my sometime to answer because I wanted to be sure that I can reverse the vector from polar cordinates to the standars ones and all went good. Thanks again !

Comment: ok! I am glad to be useful