# Restriction of vector field to the circle

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I'm working on a problem that asks me to describe a differentiable manifold structure for the circle $S^1$ and then to calculate the restriction of the vector field
$$\xi=-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x }+x\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$
 to $S^1$ in local coordinates (given by my description of the differentiable manifold structure)

My atlas for the circle is given by the charts 
$(U_1,\phi_1),(U_2,\phi_1),(U_3,\phi_1),(U_4,\phi_1)$ where $U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4$ are the upper, lower, left and right open semi-circles, respectively and 
$\phi_1(x,y)=x,\phi_2(x,y)=x,\phi_3(x,y)=y,\phi_4(x,y)=x$. I've already check that this charts are pairwise compatible so this is a correct description of the differentiable structure of $S^1$. However, I don't understand how to calculate the restriction of the vector field. I think in example 1.1 of   [this document](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/veccoord.pdf) something similar is done but with polar coordinates but I don't understand very well how. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe this will help:
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583153/change-of-coordinates-and-vector-fields .

Comment: @Nick But isn't there a problem with the circle being a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? All examples I've seen are restrictions to open subsets

Comment: That doesn't really matter, does it? you could just take a really  thin open set around the circle.